# Planting 2 tomato plants in one 20-gallon grow pot (Smart Pot)

Tags: tomatoes, pots

I bought a few [20 gallon grow pots](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0055E85OO) (20" diameter x 15.5" high), and they look quite big for one plant.

Do you think I can put two plants side by side? That'd be 10 gallons per plant. The only issue is they will end up pretty close together.

Answer (score 5):

I'd put exactly ONE in a 20" diameter pot.  Otherwise you are going to crowd them up terribly.

"Square foot" gardening recommends 1 tomato plant per 2 square foot spacing - you grid off the planting area into 1' squares and for a tomato it would take 4 of them.

Regardless of whether this is a "determinate" (bush type) or "indeterminate" (vine type) tomato, trying to put two of them in the same pot is likely to make it a jumbled mess.  Ultimately, you want some space for these to grow.

---

Addendum:

Regarding spacing of tomatoes in general, this year I spaced my tomatoes right at 3' apart and spaced the rows at 4' apart.  I use some simple cages to contain my plants - mostly indeterminate types - and those are about 2' in diameter.  So there is approximately 1' between the cages in the rows and approximately 2' of *potential* walking space in the rows.  Of course, the tomatoes extend out from the cages and so there's a bit less than that and sometimes I have to move vines to scoot around the plants.

My point in all of this is that tomatoes are plants that *need* space and will *benefit* from the space.  Having room allows air circulation and reduces the likelihood of non-insect problems.

Determinate varieties "behave" better but still perform better with space.  I'll be honest with you - I had to learn this the hard way after cramming way too many plants in a given space in an attempt to "maximize" my yields.  What I ended up doing most of the time was increasing my problems.